# GridSearch : The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have built a neural network for binary classification and am trying to find the best Hyperparameter with a GridSearch... but I get this error: "The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed." I tried the solutions of several topics but I am still stuck.
The error concerns the last line `grid_result = grid.fit(X,Y)`.
I am running the code on colab.research.google

```py
# Function to create the Binary Classification model
def create_BC_model(learning_rate, feature_layer):
    """Create and compile a simple linear regression model."""
    # Most simple tf.keras models are sequential.
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    # Add the layer containing the feature columns to the model.
    model.add(feature_layer)

    # Topography of the model
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, 
                                    activation='relu',
                                    name='Hidden1'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, 
                                    activation='relu', 
                                    name='Hidden2'))

    
    # Output layer.
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,
                                    activation=tf.sigmoid,
                                    name='Output'))                              
    
    model.compile(
                optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
                # optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=my_learning_rate),                                                   
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
                            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
                            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall")]
                )

    return model

# GridSearch

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_BC_model(0.0005,BC_feature_layer), verbose=0)

X = trainBC_df_norm[['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20',
                    '21','21','23','24']]
Y = trainBC_df_norm[['BinVal_Int2e']]

X = X.to_numpy()
Y = Y.to_numpy()

numpy.random.seed(seed)
# Split the dataset into features and label.

    
batch_size = [50, 100, 150, 200]
epochs = [500, 700, 1500]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X,Y)
```

The full error :

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

    FitFailedWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d5109af965ea> in <module>()
        25 param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
        26 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
---> 27 grid_result = grid.fit(X,Y)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    737             refit_start_time = time.time()
    738             if y is not None:
--> 739                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    740             else:
    741                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py in fit(self, x, y, **kwargs)
    221       raise ValueError('Invalid shape for y: ' + str(y.shape))
    222     self.n_classes_ = len(self.classes_)
--> 223     return super(KerasClassifier, self).fit(x, y, **kwargs)
    224 
    225   def predict(self, x, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py in fit(self, x, y, **kwargs)
    153           not isinstance(self.build_fn, types.MethodType)):
    154       self.model = self.build_fn(
--> 155           **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
    156     else:
    157       self.model = self.build_fn(**self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    940     #   not to any other argument.
    941     # - setting the SavedModel saving spec.
--> 942     inputs, args, kwargs = self._split_out_first_arg(args, kwargs)
    943     input_list = nest.flatten(inputs)
    944 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _split_out_first_arg(self, args, kwargs)
    3046     else:
    3047       raise ValueError(
-> 3048           'The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.')
    3049     return inputs, args, kwargs
    3050 

ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.
```

Comment: what is `BC_feature_layer` ? Please give a reproducible example.

Comment: "BC_feature_layer" is the names of the columns on which I run the algorithm.

Comment: then why do want to add the names of the column to model here `model.add(feature_layer)`?

Comment: This is the input layer

Answer (score 4):

I believe `KerasClassifier` requires the `build_fn` to be a function, whereas you're calling the function to return a model. You should put the arguments afterwards as keyword arguments, like so:

```py
model = KerasClassifier(create_BC_model, learning_rate=0.0005, feature_layer=BC_feature_layer, verbose=0)
```